# How to keep each tab's panel height?

Tags: lwuit

There is a `TabbedPane` of two `Tabs` :

```
tabClient.addTab("Fiche", cFicheClient);       // cFicheClient is a Container
tabClient.addTab("Crédits", cClientEtCredits); // cClientEtCredits is a Container
```

On the first `Tab` there is only few fields to display , on the second `Tab` there is a `List` containing many records not all displayed on the screen. The problem is that there is a vertical `Scrollbar` at the right of the screen even when the selected `Tab` is the first one. Here are images :
[image]
[image]
So how to make the first panel keep its own height so that there is no vertical `Scrollbar` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly just set the parent form to scrollable false.